# Stomp over websocket : The send buffer size exceeded the allowed limit

Tags: java, spring-websocket, stomp, spring-4

At client side I am using Stomp for websocket connection and server side I am using Spring 4 
 It client side I did configuration as

```
var socket = new SockJS(urlBase + "/" + contextroot+'/hello');
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
```

Below code executed for every 2 second to send data to server

```
stompClient.send('/app/sendRequest/'+indexVal, {}, 
JSON.stringify({index : simIndex}));
```

Server respond to below queue

```
stompClient.subscribe('/queue/response', processResponseObj);
```

at server side configuration done as

```
<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/app">
   <!--<websocket:transport send-timeout="15000" message-size="1051648" send-buffer-size="1051648"/> -->
   <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/hello">
       <websocket:sockjs />
   </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
   <websocket:stomp-broker-relay prefix="/topic, /queue"  />

    <websocket:message-converters>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter">
        <beans:property name="objectMapper" ref="objectMapper" />
       </beans:bean>
    </websocket:message-converters>

    </websocket:message-broker>
```

Message responsded as at server side

```
 messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/queue/response",obj);
```

After some second I am getting error message

```
2014-10-24 16:39:33,869 ERROR et.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler: 330 - Terminating session id 'dkbzrkxp'
org.springframework.web.socket.handler.SessionLimitExceededException: The send buffer size 1147188 bytes for session 'dkbzrkxp exceeded the allowed limit 1051648
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.sessionLimitReached(ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.java:162) ~[ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.checkSessionLimits(ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.java:150) ~[ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.sendMessage(ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.java:105) ~[ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.StompSubProtocolHandler.handleMessageToClient(StompSubProtocolHandler.java:276) ~[StompSubProtocolHandler.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.handleMessage(SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:326) ~[SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel$1.run(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:70) [ExecutorSubscribableChannel$1.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_20]
2014-10-24 16:39:33,871  WARN ort.session.WebSocketServerSockJsSession: 285 - Failed to send SockJS close frame: The remote endpoint was in state [TEXT_PARTIAL_WRITING] which is an invalid state for called method
2014-10-24 16:39:33,875 ERROR et.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler: 330 - Terminating session id 'nro1ww4x'
org.springframework.web.socket.handler.SessionLimitExceededException: The send buffer size 1147188 bytes for session 'nro1ww4x exceeded the allowed limit 1051648
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.sessionLimitReached(ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.java:162) ~[ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.checkSessionLimits(ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.java:150) ~[ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.sendMessage(ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.java:105) ~[ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.StompSubProtocolHandler.handleMessageToClient(StompSubProtocolHandler.java:276) ~[StompSubProtocolHandler.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.handleMessage(SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:326) ~[SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel$1.run(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:70) [ExecutorSubscribableChannel$1.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_20]
2014-10-24 16:39:33,876  WARN ort.session.WebSocketServerSockJsSession: 285 - Failed to send SockJS close frame: The remote endpoint was in state [TEXT_PARTIAL_WRITING] which is an invalid state for called method
2014-10-24 16:39:34,833 ERROR standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter:  55 - Closing due to exception for WebSocket session id=0
```

I tried with increasing buffer size also but after some time its giving same exception. once buffer size reached.

I think websocket session buffer not released once message delivered.

Is there any setting requird for same?
Did i missed any configuration ?

Comment: Did you solved this issue? I facing with the same problem

Comment: resolved by adding registration.setMessageSizeLimit(102400* 1024);

Answer (score 13):

Try to configure the web socket on the server side.
Something like this int the WebSocketConfig class:

```
 public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration registration) {
    registration.setMessageSizeLimit(500 * 1024);
    registration.setSendBufferSizeLimit(1024 * 1024);
    registration.setSendTimeLimit(20000);
}
```

Comment: adding to @skywalker's answer, I found this spring doc page you can refer to (such as default values for the msg size limit, buffer size limit, and so forth)
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/WebSocketTransportRegistration.html