# Spring boot - Websocket buffer size limit

Tags: java, spring, websocket

I'm trying to increase buffer size of my WebSocket but I couldn't achieve that. When I send message over 65536 I've got :

*org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompConversionException: The 'content-length' header 447721  exceeds the configured message buffer size limit 65536*

Here's my WebSocekt Configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {



    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/queue", "/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }

}
```

What should I add in my code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543904/stomp-over-websocket-the-send-buffer-size-exceeded-the-allowed-limit

Comment: Thanks, that's work for me :)